# What are the different techniques I can use to get past the man-eating plants?

Tags: trine-2

What are the different techniques I can use to get past the man-eating plants, if I have no choice but to go near their attack range? Or if I want to get an experience orb or vial that is in their path?

[image]

I know that Zoya's (the Thief) 'Stealth Movement' skill and Pontius' (the Knight) 'Charge' skill can be used to get through without being caught, even if you are going near the plants' attack range. Are there techniques that don't require the use of special skills? What about other special skills that can be used to get past them? (Getting past can also mean distracting the plants, so that they don't try to catch you, when you get near them.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Technique 1: use the fireflies

The plants eat fireflies. Usually in the vicinity of the plants you find a swarm of fireflies flying around, and a lamp or two lying on the ground. Use telekinesis to move the lamp into the swarm to gather the fireflies, then move the lamp-with-fireflies into range of the plant. The plant will consume the fireflies and will then rest for a few seconds, ignoring you and allowing you free reign within its range.

Once the plant eats the fireflies, that trick cannot be used again until you gather up another bunch of them. You can reuse the same lamp for that (the plants only eats the fireflies, not the lamp). You can also reuse the same swarm of fireflies to recharge the lamp, those seem to never get exhausted.

[Here's a video segment of someone feeding the plant](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=KOq1p210NTE#t=780s) - you can see the swallow and rest animation.

#### Technique 2: swing really fast

When Zoya swings with a long rope length she moves really fast. That is sometimes fast enough to swing past a plant. It's still risky, though.

#### Technique 3: fall through them

When you fall you move fast enough so that the plants can't get you. If you can engineer your movement through their range so that it's almost only falling down, you can occasionally get through alive.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the man-eating plant finds goblins just as tasty as fireflies :)